# In C# is it possible to initialize a variable with two possible types?

Tags: c#, types, initialization

In a C# function, I have a local variable that could be one of two types depending on the case. What would be the most effective way of initializing it?

What I'd like to do (with the two types being float and bool for simplicity):

```cs
bool myCase = GetCase(); // Externally initialized
var myVar; // Cannot do this as implicitly-typed variables must be initialized

if (myCase) {
    myVar = GetFloat();
}
else {
    myVar = GetBool();
}

// Do whatever with myVar
```

I could solve this by doing the two initializations but in my specific use case, the two possible types are more complex than simple bool and float so ideally I'd like to only use one initialization.

```cs
bool myCase = GetCase(); // Externally initialized
float myVarAsAFloat = GetFloat(); // Expensive to do both initialization
float myVarAsABool = GetBool(); // Expensive to do both initialization

// Do whatever with either myVarAsAFloat or myVarAsABool
```

Comment: How does the code that follows `// Do whatever with myVar` know what operations are valid for `myVar`? The whole point of giving a variable a type is to tell the code what it can do with it.

Comment: https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the type?

Comment: @JohnWu the code knows what operations to do based on the same boolean `myCase`. For instance: `if (myCase) {FunctionRequiringFloatAsInput(myVar)} else {FunctionRequiringBoolAsInput(myVar)}`

Comment: The most popular NuGet package to support this (with 16M downloads) is [`OneOf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OneOf) - worth a look.

Comment: The answer of JonasH tells you how to do this if you must. However, _**must you**_? In my experience, "a local variable that could be one of two types depending on the case" means, with almost complete certainty, that you have a hopelessly wrong design in your hands.  This type of hack is discouraged even in scripting languages, where variables do not even have types to begin with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A value that can have one of two possible types is called a [Tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) in computer science terms. See the link for synonyms.

There is no builtin support for such types. But you can make one using generics. Such types are sometimes called 'Either', i.e. `Either<T1, T2>`.

These typically take a functional approach since this concept is much more common in functional languages like Haskel, so it might look something like

```
public Either<bool, float> GetVar(bool myCase){
  if (myCase) {
    return GetFloat();
  }
  else {
    return GetBool();
  }
}
...
var myVar = GetVar(true);

var varAsString = myVar.Select(myBool => myBool.ToString(), myFloat => myFloat.ToString("0.#"));
```

There are various libraries for such a type, [first google hit](https://gist.github.com/jonfunkhouser/de0d9f5dc2dd5e6dd8cb). Google "C# either monad" to get a bunch of articles and code.

Do note that there is a fair amount of variation in naming, design etc between libraries. I have tried to use the most common terms I have seen, but there are certainly others in use.

Also note that this is just one way to do it, you can also use inheritance to describe the same thing, or keep explicit flags to determine what value is valid. The best approach will depend on many different factors.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should create a factory class which resolves the correct implementation of a generic interface like `ICanDoSomething<T>`, so a class like `BoolHandler` impl. `ICanDoSomething<bool>`. Here's an example:

```
public interface ICanDoSomething
{
    public void Do();
}

public interface ICanDoSomething<T>: ICanDoSomething
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class BoolHandler: ICanDoSomething<bool>
{
    public BoolHandler(bool value) => Value = value;
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public void Do()
    {
        // do something with bool value
    }
}

public class FloatHandler : ICanDoSomething<float>
{
    public FloatHandler(float value) => Value = value;
    public float Value { get; set; }

    public void Do()
    {
        // do something with float value
    }
}

public class HandlerFactory
{
    public ICanDoSomething? GetHandler(object value)
    {
        return value switch
        {
            bool b => new BoolHandler(b),
            float f => new FloatHandler(f),
            _ => null
        };
    }
}
```

So how you would use this? Look here:

```
HandlerFactory factory = new();
object value = true;
ICanDoSomething? handler = factory.GetHandler(value);
handler?.Do();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZCQLbB

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to handle this is to assign the variable in the same conditional block that knows what type it is. Each block has its own scope so you can reuse the same variable name if you wish.

For example:

```
bool myCase = GetCase(); // Externally initialized
if (myCase)
{
    var myVar = GetFloat();
    FunctionRequiringFloatAsInput(myVar)
}
else
{
    var myVar = GetBool();
    FunctionRequiringBoolAsInput(myVar);
}
```

While you *could* use an `object` or `dynamic` or a tagged union, these are generally not recommended.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use an `object`, it's the closest thing C# has to a [variant type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type_(COM)).

```
bool myCase = GetCase();
object myVar;

if (myCase) {
    myVar = GetFloat();
} else {
    myVar = GetBool();
}
```

If that isn't good enough, you can use a type library [like this one](https://github.com/vladris/Maki.NET) which implements both `Variant<...>` and `Either<T1, T2>` among other things.